# getting first non display number in use

Tags: ubuntu, x-server, shell-script, xvfb

I need to give  a command like

Xvfb :6 -screen 0 1024x768x24

Where 6 can be a display number. Now Xvfb can already be using that Display, so how do I get the first display number not in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but I'd write a script that queries the displays with ***xdpyinfo***.

There are pretty much 3 cases:

1. The display exists, and your shell has access to the display.  *xdpyinfo* will spit out lots of info.
2. The display exists, and your shell *doesn't* have access to the display.  *xdpyinfo* will spit out an access error and an unable-to-open error, like this:
   `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":0".`
3. The display doesn't exist.  *xdpyinfo* will spit out an unable-to-open error:
   `xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":1".`

A script would look a bit like this:

```
#/bin/bash
CHECKDISPLAY=0
DONE="no"

while [ "$DONE" == "no" ]
do
   out=$(xdpyinfo -display :$CHECKDISPLAY 2>&1)
   if [[ "$out" == name* ]] || [[ "$out" == Invalid* ]]
   then
      # command succeeded; or failed with access error;  display exists
      (( CHECKDISPLAY+=1 ))
   else
      # display doesn't exist
      DONE="yes"
   fi
done

echo "first available display is :$CHECKDISPLAY"
```

Answer (score 2):

xvfb-run has a flag `--auto-servernum` which works by looking for the X lock files in `/tmp`.

Squished into a single line that you could alias in your .bashrc, it looks like this:

```
i=0; while [ -f /tmp/.X$i-lock ]; do i=$(($i + 1)); done; echo $i
```

If you are simply trying to run a program with the display set to Xvfb, I would just use xvfb-run.